# Simple NOR gate (transistor-level) diagram

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

My question here is simple:

[image: Schematic]

I cannot understand how the input flows throughout the circuit.  I understand the P and N type transistors; I could see why if A and B are both 0, and pass through the P-transistors, their value will be 1, and C will be 1.  But I don't believe that's the right interpretation.

So what  I don't get is -- what of the N transistors?  I drew a red and blue path for input A, to clarify.  How do I know where A goes?  What should I take into account for determining the output of C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a 0 is applied to a P gate then think of it as a short-circuit. If a 1 is applied to a P gate then think of it as an open-circuit.

Each input, A and B are both going into 1 P gate and 1 N gate *each*. Now let's walk through the truth table.

A=0, B=0. Both P gates are short circuits and both N gates are open circuits. Therefore C is tied directly to the upper "1" voltage and is completely separated by an open circuit from the bottom "0" voltage, C=1.

A=0, B=1. The P gate B touches is an open-circuit and the other P gate is a short-circuit. C does not have a direct path to the upper "1" anymore. Moreover, the N gate that B is tied to is now a short-circuit which will tie C directly to the lower "0" voltage, C=0.

A=1, B=0. Basically the same as the previous state. You should be able to work it out yourself.

A=1, B=1. See if you can work it out yourself to see why C will equal 0.

Comment: Ok this clarifies everything for me, particularly as to how C can get cut off at the the top if one of them remains open.  Thanks!

Comment: Great. The A and B inputs are basically just controlling switches which will determine the output. They never "flow" to the output.

Answer (score 1):

A goes to both the P and N transistors.  If A is low, then the top transistor conducts and the second transistor connected to A does not.  If B is also low, then its upper transistor conducts but its lower one doesn't.  The upper transistors pull C up, and the lower transistors do nothing.

Now, let A be high.  A's upper transistor doesn't conduct, but the bottom one does and pulls C down.

The series structure at the top means that both A and B have to be low in order for C to be high.  If either one is high, then C isn't pulled up and one of the lower transistors will pull it down.

Comment: Thank you!  So to clarify with the pulling up/down concept.  What if B (0) pulls up, and A (1) pulls down.  How does that necessarily entail C being a 0?

Answer (score 1):

You could think of this as two gates- one is an AND gate with inverted inputs that can only drive high (AND with inverted inputs is logically the same as a NOR). That's the two p-channel transistors in series. Both inputs must be low for the output to be driven high (open drain, so it cannot drive low, only high).

The second is a NOR gate. That's the two n-channel transistors. If either input is high then the output is driven low (open drain, so it cannot drive high, only low).

If you look at the possible states for the inputs, there are four. 00 01 10 and 11.

In the case of 00, the two p-channel transistors come into play and the output is driven high. The two n-channel transistors are both off so they don't fight. In every other case, one or both of the n-channel transistors is on, and one or both of the p-channel transistors is off, so it is driven low (and again, they don't fight).

Comment: I like your analysis very much. "two gates", "AND gate with inverted inputs that can only drive high" "NOR gate ... it cannot drive high, only low". I feel like "the scales fell from my eyes", +1